# HTML5 input date showing incorrect language for months on iOS7

Tags: html, date, mobile, ios7, safari

I'm attempting to use an HTML 5 input date tag for mobile Safari on iOS7, specifically with the iPhone set to the French language. The months that are listed in the date picker control that shows up on focus are in English and not French, while the buttons are indeed in French. Is there something I've missed here, or is this a mobile Safari bug?

My incredibly complex code is below.

```
<input type="date" />
```

Thanks!
Chris

[image: French months incorrect]

Comment: do you have `<html lang="fr">`?

Comment: useful links http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iOS_7_UIPickerView_Example  and http://team.158ltd.com/2013/12/21/ios-how-to-make-datepicker/

Comment: @RachelGallen That's for native iOS code and doesn't apply to me.

Answer (score -1):

Turns out there's a region setting that the date input reads to determine which language the months should be shown in. Settings --> General --> International --> Region Format. In my case, I had to go to "French" and then "Canada". I still had to change the language of the device to French to get the buttons to show up in the correct language.