# How to change <input type='date'> placeholder language from Cyrillic to English (дд.мм.рррр to dd.mm.yyyy)?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on form that must contain input with date type using Formik and Styled Components. And need its "placeholder" to be shown in english but its show me cyrylic instead.

I understand that my browser uses it's own preferences to decide how to show me that placeholder. But I need it to be in english by default for enyone regardles of browser language.
Base language of page also en.
[Meaning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdSTA.png)

My current input looks like this in browser.

Current state of input field

[image: 2]

I tried to change lang parameter of input to "en-GB" or "en-US" but it does not help.

Input field in code

[image: 3]

Is there any way to achive that?

Edit: [Styles of date field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1I0GU.png) for more info

Comment: What is `ModalDateField`?

Comment: *"Base language of page also en."* Would you show us the markup doing that? In case we can see an issue with it.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24250521/html5-input-date-showing-incorrect-language-for-months-on-ios7, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43026440/why-do-browsers-ignore-lang-when-rendering-content, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43026440/why-do-browsers-ignore-lang-when-rendering-content

Comment: From the links above, it's looking like this is hard or impossible to do. :-| Which is really surprising.

Comment: ModalDateField is styled component  styled(Field) where Field is from Formik

Comment: The title asks about `input type="date"`, not Formik `Field`...?

Comment: I changed styled(Field) to styled.input but with same result. As far as i know Formik Field when get property type='date' become just regular <input type="date">